# Outlier Analysis / Frequency Distribution

Tags: sql, statistics

I can use standard deviation analysis to identify outliers on columns with numeric values.  But what about discrete / text based values?

For example, is the value "Blue" an outlier in this case?
  8 records in table X with a value of "Purple"
  5 records in table X with a value of "Red"
  3 records in table X with a value of "Green"
  2 records in table X with a value of "Blue"
In this case, my view is no, "Blue" is not an outlier.

Using another example:
  451 records in table X with a value of "Purple"
  345 records in table X with a value of "Red"
  233 records in table X with a value of "Green"
  2 records in table X with a value of "Blue"
In this case, "Blue" sure is an outlier.  Which is not to say it is necessarily invalid, just off the beaten path.

What I'm hoping to come up with, if possible, is something like:  "Blue" gets flagged because its frequency of occurrence is 3 standard deviations off of the mean...

Comment: What is your sql engine, what are your table schemas -- post some code, please.

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly what you asked for but you can compare your distribution against another distribution (perhaps one you know or one you assume) using the chi-square goodness of fit test. http://stattrek.com/chi-square-test/goodness-of-fit.aspx